# Can we declare a object inside the if-else statement?

Tags: c++

This code is the main function for  the implementation of queues using arrays also using template class.

```
int main(){
    int choice, n;

    cout<<"Enter 1 for integer 2 for double\n";
    cin >> choice;
    cout<<"Enter the size of queue\n";
    cin>>n;

    if (choice == 1)
        queue<int> obj(n);
    else
      queue<double> obj(n);

    for(;;){
        cout<<"1:Insertrear 2:Deletefront 3:Display 4:Exit\n";
        cin >> choice;

        switch(choice){
            case 1:obj.insertRear();break;
            case 2:obj.deleteFront(); break;
            case 3:obj.display();break;
            default: return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The thing that I could not understand is, why I got error `'obj' was not declared in this scope` in the line below the `switch` statement.

Any help will be well appreciated.

Comment: The static type of an object can never depend on user input. So even in principal what you are trying to do can't be done. Is `obj` suppose to be `queue<int>` or `queue<double>`? You can only know at runtime so it's not possible. You can work around that, for example you could use a `std::variant<std::queue<int>, std::queue<double>>` though that has it's own set of challenges. Otherwise, you would need to come up with a unified interface that both queues can respect and implement your own queues with that interface, using polymorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: Yes, you can declare objects inside `if` and `else` blocks, but they will be destroyed while leaving this blocks. In fact, after the `if` block there is no `obj` anymore.

Your idea to have different data types represented by a single object, depending on other runtime variables will not work in c++. C++ has a strong type system which makes your code idea impossible. That can be done on languages like python, but not at all by c++.

If you have the same algorithm, which should be used for different data types, you can play with templates. But this will still generate the complete code multiple times, a single instance per used data type.

From C++17 you can use `std::variant` to have a container, which can contain different data types during runtime. But that comes with the cost, that there is an additional value ( tag ), which tells the rest of the code which data type is currently stored in the variant itself. On every access the compiler has to generate something like `if ( data == int ) then ...` In detail it will be handled a bit different ( jumptable for different methods to call ). `variant` can also be used from other libraries like boost before C++17.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we declare a object inside the if-else statement?

Yes.

> The thing that I could not understand is, why I got error 'obj' was not declared in this scope in the line below the switch statement.

The (potential) scope of a local variable declared within a if statement extends to the end of the statement where it was declared. Example:

```
if (choice == 1) {
    queue<int> obj(n);
    // obj is in scope here
}
// obj is no longer in scope
else {
    queue<double> obj(n);
    // obj that is in cope here is not the same variable
}
// neither obj is in scope here
```

You're attempting to refer to that variable from outside of its scope. The life-time of the object has ended, and the name is no longer in scope.

---

C++ is a statically typed language. The type of a variable must be known at compile time and cannot change at run time.

A typical solution is to use a function template:

```
template<class T>
int do_things() {
    queue<T> obj(n);
    for(;;){
        // ...
    }
}

// in main
if (choice == 1)
    return do_things<int>();
else
    return do_things<double>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because of scoping. The scope of the obj ends in your if / else and is not visible outside.

For your use case an extra bit of indirection may help. If your template queue class has a base, you can define a pointer to the base class outside the if else scope and assign the strongly typed instances inside the if / else and use the base class pointer in your switch statement.